# Outlook Web App: Retrieve contacts

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on developing outlook web addin which runs on both outlook365 and outlook.com. I have a requirement to create, read and update contacts using that web addin. Below is the sample which add current user to `To` field of an email.

```
function addToRecipients() {
    var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    var addressToAdd = {
        displayName: Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName,
        emailAddress: Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress
    };

    if (item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
        Office.cast.item.toMessageCompose(item).to.addAsync([addressToAdd]);
    } else if (item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment) {
        Office.cast.item.toAppointmentCompose(item).requiredAttendees.addAsync([addressToAdd]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out me how i can retrieve the outlook contacts using outlook web addin ?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to access the contacts in the Contacts Folder of Outlook? This is not currently possible via the APIs that have been provided.

Features requests and suggestions should go to https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Actually to update this, you can use the REST API to grab contacts/add them. The documentation is on http://dev.outlook.com/

It is doubtful that direct access to contacts will be added to the JS API.

Comment: @TimWan Thanks. I'm able to accomplish it using `Office.context.mailbox.makeewsRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, makeEwsRequestAsync API is one way to do it with JS API.

Comment: do you have any code samples? how did you get an email address from the exchange?